# How to catch by a particular app the SMS just from particular sender?

Tags: android

I need your advice with the following task. The point is that I need to hold my app with a particular mobile number so that the device with my app will reacts just on the SMS from this number and other numbers should be caught with the standard or any other third-party apps. I need it because the SMS should contain specific data that can be decoded just with a special app.

So, what should I do to realize it or what the wilds should be inspected by me:) ?

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: When u will be able to read the sms, then u can filter it by the phone number or whatever u want. Just get the sms first... http://andro-source.blogspot.com/2013/02/sms-reading-in-android-programmatically.html

Comment: Note that what you want is not possible as of Android 4.4, insofar as *all* SMS messages are delivered the user's chosen default SMS client.

Comment: @CommonsWare, And, what is up to earlier versions? Is it realizable?

Comment: It should be possible, using the recipe in LokiSinclair's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you'll need to do something along these lines:

1. Add required permissions to your manifest. Probably `RECEIVE_SMS`
2. Create an SMS `BroadcastReceiver`
3. Handle incoming SMS's inside your receiver
4. Choose to consume the message (if only applicable to your app), or let the stock sms app pick it up.

None of the following code is tested, more a starting point:

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<receiver android:name=".YOURSMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="SOMENUMBER">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**YOURSMSReceiver**

```
public class YOURSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
     @Override
     public void onReceiver(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
         boolean bConsumeSms = false;            // flag to consume the sms so stock app doesn't pick it up

         String data = "";
         if(intent.getAction().equals(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED))
         {
             Bundle bundlePdus = intent.getExtras();
             Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundlePdus.get("pdus");
             SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[0]);
             if(messages.getOriginatingAddress() == YOURCELLNUMBER)
             {
                  // do something with the content. 
                  // held in: messages.getMessageBody()
                  data = messages.getMessageBody();    // your custom content

                  // consume this sms
                  bCOnsume = true;
             }

             // in order to consume the message, we have to use abortBroadcast(). But only if we've
             // processed it first. If not, then the stock app, should be allowed to pick it up
             if(bConsume)
             {
                   abortBroadcast();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

As I've said, its completely untested, but in theory everything you need is there. You'll also have to handle multiple messages, which is something I've not bothered with, based on the size of the pdu array. Good luck!

**Edit** CommonsWare has pointed out that 4.4 Android OS delivers all SMS regardless. I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: Thank you for such descriptive explanation.